# County choropleth skipping counties

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to make a choropleth map using d3 and jenks natural breaks using the example here: http://bl.ocks.org/tmcw/4969184

My `json` file looks like:

```
{
  "type": "Topology",
  "objects": {
    "counties": {
      "type": "GeometryCollection",
      "bbox": [-179.1473399999999, 17.674395666000066, 179.77848000000006, 71.38921046500008],
      "geometries": [
        {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "properties": {
            "fips": "01001",
            "name": "Autauga County",
            "state": "AL"
          },
          "id": "01001",
          "arcs": [[0,1,2,3,4]]
        }, …
```

And my `csv` is:

```
fips,value
01001,0.097
01003,0.091
01005,0.134
01007,0.121
01009,0.099
01011,0.164
…
```

This is my `d3` code:

```
var scales = {};

var rateById = d3.map();

var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
    .scale(1200);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

// Draw here!
queue()
.defer(d3.json, "data/us-10m.json")
.defer(d3.csv, "data/data.csv")
.await(ready);

function ready(error, us, data) {
    var rateById = {};

    data.forEach(function(d) { rateById[d.fips] = +d.value; });

    // jenks
    var jenksDomain = ss.jenks(data.map(function(d) { return +d.value; }), 9);

    scales.jenks9 = d3.scale.threshold()
        .domain(jenksDomain)
        .range(d3.range(9).map(function(i) { return "q" + i + "-9"; }));

    //create map svg
    svg = d3.select("#graphic").append("svg");

    //draw counties
    var counties = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "counties")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path);

    //style each county
    function setScale(s) {
        counties.attr("class", function(d) { 
        return d.properties.state + " " + 
        d.properties.name + " " + 
        scales[s](rateById[d.id]); })
    }

    setScale('jenks9');

    // draw state outlines
    chartElement.append("path")
        .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
        .attr("class", "states")
        .attr("d", path);
};
```

And my result:

[image]

As you can see, some counties don't seem to get colored in at all and the `scales[s](rateById[d.id])` returns `undefined` when I inspect those counties using the Web Inspector.

Each of them seems to be a county where there the FIPS code has "skipped" one on either side. For example, the southernmost county in Arizona, Pima County, Arizona, has a FIPS code of `04019`. There are no `04018` or `04020`, it goes from `04017` (Navajo County, AZ) to `04019` (Pima County, AZ) and then `04020` (Pimal County, AZ). This seems to be the commonality between all the counties that don't get filled in with the JavaScript, but I can't figure out how to fix this.